# Выключить вывод в браузер и сохранить в переменную php как?

Tags: php

Насколько я знаю есть функции: ob_start, ob_get_contents, но они же не выключают вывод на экран (в браузер). Мне не нужно вывод на экран нужно сохранить в переменной ob_get_contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

простой пример

```
ob_start();
echo "Test";
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

В переменной $output получите значение "Test". При этом код не выведет ничего в браузер или консоль. Можете проверить.

Но если выполнить var_dump($output), увидим

```
string(4) "Test"
```

Comment: Да, все есть, большое спасибо! Я просто сейчас на руби больше пишу!